# UIBubbleTableView to fetch didSelectRowAtIndexPath from NSBubbleData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, chat, tableview

hi i am using [code](http://alexbarinov.github.io/UIBubbleTableView/) to create chat view its working fine,but i need to add enlarge image on click so in UIBubbleTableView.m class i added following code to get index selected value.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"value of index=%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row]);
    NSLog(@"value of selected section=%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",     [[self.bubbleSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row - 1]]);

 }
```

it gives following output :

value of selected section=

**how i get text or image from the above NSBubbleData??**

The data pass in this code have following format

```
//for photo
NSBubbleData *photoBubblenew = [NSBubbleData dataWithImage:image date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-0] type:BubbleTypeMine];

//for text
NSBubbleData *  TextBubble = [NSBubbleData dataWithText:@"Hi,Check out Iphonelover" date:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-300] type:BubbleTypeSomeoneElse];
```

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to do - Assuming that self.bubbleSection is an array of arrays of NSBubbleData and assuming you are using NSBubbleData from here https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView/blob/master/src/NSBubbleData.h then it exposes a UIView, not a string

Comment: hey Paulw, how can i get value of that view and Guess it contain text or image?
I need to do: if it contain image then enlarge it and if it contain text then provide feature to translate etc

Comment: The `view` property contains the reference to the `UIView`.

Comment: please explain Paulw how i can use it?

Comment: I guess you will need a table cell that can hold a view and you need to assign the view to the cell's view.  You will also need to provide the appropriate value from tableview:heightForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put Label TAG HERE...

```
 -(id)initWithText:(NSString *)text date:(NSDate *)date type:(NSBubbleType)type
{

    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]];
    CGSize size = [(text ? text : @"") sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;

    label.text = (text ? text : @"");
    label.font = font;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.tag=100;

    UIEdgeInsets insets = (type == BubbleTypeMine ? textInsetsMine : textInsetsSomeone);
    return [self initWithView:label date:date type:type insets:insets];}
```

Then Get the Value HERE

```
NSBubbleData *bubble=Chat_DATA [indexPath.row];

UIView *view=bubble.view;

UILabel *LBL=(UILabel*) [view viewWithTag:100];

NSString *msg=LBL.text;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of indexPath.row is not a string. You can't log it with %@. Try using %i or %li, which are used for integers.